# Dynamically create INSERT query using Javascript object with MariaDB/node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I want to **insert key/value pairs** of data into a **mariaDB** using **MariaDB Node.js Connector**

**Data object:**

- The key in my data object corresponds to the column identifier of my SQL table
- I have around 15 different columns, and sometimes I only need two or three, sometimes 10
- therefore i look for a dynamic solution, to just pass the data obj to my database and insert a new row, even with empty fields

```
var data = { 
    col1: 313,
    col2: "test2",
    col3: "test3",
    ...
    colX: "testX"
}
```

**SQL Table 'foo':**

| ID | col1 | col2 | ... | colX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUTO_INCREMENTAL | data1 | data2 | ... | data3 |

**Question:**

**1)** I found some examples with syntax "INSERT INTO table SET ?" but I can't get these running as I always get parse errors. It his functionality included in the node.js MariaDB connector?

**2)** Is there a more elegant way of creating an INSERT query then the following?
With this syntax, if my data object has a mixed order (e.g. col1, col3, col2) , data are also inserted in the wrong order.

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2, col3,...,colX) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,...?)"
con.query(sql, [data], function(err, result){});
```

**3)**  Is there a way to simplify syntax to get something like this?

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO foo SET ?)"
con.query(sql, [data], function(err, result){});
```

Comment: see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/

Answer (score 0):

I made a small function to help me parsing an SQL statement:

```js
var allowedFields = ['foo', 'foo2'];

function parseSqlFieldNames(field_names) {

  if (field_names === undefined) return "";

  let sql = "";

  while (field_names.length > 0) {
    let field = field_names.pop();

    if (allowedFields.includes(field)) {
      if (field_names.length == 0) {
        sql = sql + "`" + field + "`"
      } else {
        sql = sql + "`" + field + "`,"
      }
    } else {
      console.error('example.js: parseSqlFieldNames(): field not in allowed list');
    }
  }
  return sql;
}


function getSqlString(field_names) {

  let placeholder = "?,";
  let totalFields = field_names.length; // save for placeholder as pop() is used

  let sql = "INSERT INTO `example_table` (";
  sql = sql + parseSqlFieldNames(field_names);
  sql = sql + ",`date_updated`) VALUES (";
  sql = sql + placeholder.repeat(totalFields)
  sql = sql + "current_date())";

  return sql;
}

console.log(getSqlString(['foo', 'foo2']))
```

**Output:**

```
INSERT INTO `example_table` ( `foo2`,  `foo` ,`date_updated`) VALUES (?,?,current_date())
```

To make the database query only two arrays of field names ['foo', 'foo2'] and variables [foo, foo2] must be passed:

```
let conn;
try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();        
    await conn.query("USE example_database");

    let sql_statement = getSqlString(['foo', 'foo2']);
    const res = await conn.query(sql_statement, [foo, foo2]);

} catch (err) {
    throw err;
} finally {
    if (conn) conn.end();
}
```